# Count Facebook photo / post / Share / comment

Tags: jquery, facebook, count, facebook-like

I try to count like on Facebook photo / post / Share / comment with Jquery or PHP , but all explain is out of date because facebook upadate API.

Thanks you for your help !

I try this but doesn't work for photo ...

```
function fbLikeCount($id,$appid,$appsecret){
    //Construct a Facebook URL
    $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?access_token='.$appid.'|'.$appsecret.'&fields=likes';
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $json_output = json_decode($json);

    //Extract the likes count from the JSON object
    if($json_output->likes){
        return $likes = $json_output->likes;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

echo fbLikeCount('xxxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

> $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?access_token='.$appid.'|'.$appsecret.'&fields=likes';

Change it with:

> $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/likes'.'?access_token='.$appid.'|'.$appsecret;

**And Also Use**

```
$likes = $json_output->data;

foreach($likes as $result) {
    echo $result->id . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi :)I have this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/21/d181465893/htdocs/vfadesign/content/fcontest.php on line 488  = Line 488 is : foreach($likes as $result) {
    echo $result->id . '<br>';
}